# Why did I get an error when I created two factories with different js file but both registered to common.services module?

Tags: angularjs

Why did I get an error when I created two factories with different js file but both registered to common.services module? But when I put the two factories in one js file , the application works? I am using angular JS on my application. Thanks.

This is the error I get
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productServiceProvider <- productService <- productDetailController

```
This is the ProductResource.js file

    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('common.services')
        .factory('productResource', ['$resource', productResource]);


This is the ProductService.js

     (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('common.services')
        .factory('productService', productService);

This is the common.services.js

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('common.services', ['ngResource']);

}());

This is the Index.html file
 <!--Application scripts-->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!--Services-->
    <script src="app/Services/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/productResource.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/productResourceMock.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/productService.js"></script>
```

This is the app.js file

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('mockApplication', ['common.services', 'ui.router', 'ui.mask', 'ui.bootstrap', 'productResourceMock']);
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Show us the error as well.

Comment: Most probably the order of injecting the HTML files. But as @Gonzalo and Pascal Winter said, we need the code and the error.